# Primary key of nested realm objects in Android

Tags: android, realm

I'm having a problem with Realm complaining about duplicate primary keys. Here's the issue:

I have two Realm Classes. I need to access both separately, and also, there is a many-to-one relationship from one to the other.

Topic:

```
public class Topic extends RealmObject{

    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;

    private String subject;
    }
```

and Question:

```
public class Question extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String _id;
    private RealmList<Option> options = null;
    private RealmList<Answer> answer;
    private Topic topic;
}
```

More than one question can have the same topic. However, when I try to create the Realm Question DB, Realm throws the RealmPrimaryKeyConstraintException: Value already exists: exception. And the exception is thrown with a the primary key of the **Topic** class.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Did you mean to have _id in the Topic declaration?

Comment: No. The topic 'id' is different (unique to a topic) from the Question '_id' (unique to the question). The naming is just the way it's been set up on the server database

Comment: People typically get that error when they use `createObject()` without specifying an id for the object on creation, or sometimes `copyToRealm()` instead of `copyToRealmOrUpdate()` does that. Considering the transaction code is not shown, we don't actually see the actual cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution from [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/2730) in the Realm Github. My code *should* have worked since I was already using primary keys for both classes and `copyToRealmOrUpdate` for creating the objects.

However, I was creating the Questions table before the Topics table, which was why Realm was trying to copy new objects to the Topics table. Apparently `copyToRealmOrUpdate` doesn't automatically assume a `copyToRealmOrUpdate` behaviour for the nested Realm objects.

Just reversing the order of creation fixed it, since (from the Github link), Realm handles already existing objects just fine if both classes have primary keys.

This may be a bug in Realm?

Comment: `copyToRealmOrUpdate` should work recursively. If you can reproduce this in a sample project and create an issue on our Github page, it would help a lot: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues

Comment: I will do this early next week and edit this comment with the issue when done.